# Why is z-index being ignored?

Tags: html, css

Why is z-index being ignored ? I expected the div with red background to cover the entire window.

```css
.nav-bar {
  background: #673ab7;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -100;
}

.nav-bar div {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 1em;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav-bar__section {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2.5rem;
}

.title-bar {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.side-bar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <div class="nav-bar__section">
      Book Collection
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="side-bar">

  </div>
  <div class="title-bar">
    My Collection
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Resulting HTML

[image]

Comment: you can probably add some description?

Comment: `width: 30%;` ? or missing `top:0` ?

Comment: z-index isn't being ignored. The red section is limited by its width, per your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the top position on `.side-bar`:

```css
.nav-bar {
  background: #673ab7;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -100;
}

.nav-bar div {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 1em;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav-bar__section {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2.5rem;
}

.title-bar {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.side-bar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <div class="nav-bar__section">
    Book Collection
  </div>
</div>
<div class="side-bar">

</div>
<div class="title-bar">
  My Collection
</div>
```

Comment: It works. I am lost on why my original code did not work. Since I have specified a z-index for side bar I expected it to overwrite without specifying `top:0`. What is the rule I am missing here ?

Comment: @ArunM you are missing nothing, when you don't set top/left/right/bottom the element will be positioned using it's initial position (like if you didn't set position fixed)